# How to remove each element from a string in python?

Tags: python

I want to remove each element from a string.
For example:
s= "abcde"
now I want to remove first "e" then "d" till s is empty.

Comment: ...Why not just `s = ""`?

Comment: `stuff = ""; rev_str = reversed(s); for char in rev_str:..stuff += char; ...print(rev_str.rstrip(stuff))` ?

Comment: I guess this is an exercise to teach you something, do you know about python and iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slices:

```
s = 'abcde'
for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
    print(s[:i])
```

Comment: :It is still keeping "a" in my s string. I tried playing with range but its not helpful

Comment: @Neha Gaikwad You can change the loop to: for i in range(len(s), -1, -1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use slice operator as:

```
s='abcde'
for i in range(len(s), -1, -1):
    s = s[:i]
print(s)
```

## Output:    ''

Comment: It is still keeping "a" in my s string. I tried playing with range but its not helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'abcde'
c = list(s) # this line converts the string to array of 
                  # characters [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 


while c:   # loop till array is empty
  c.pop() # Retrieve elements from the array end and 
                # remove it from array
```

Output:

```
'e'
'd'
'c'
'b'
'a'
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you for the feedback. I have made the necessary changes.